# Transform origin of nested element in complex SVG group

Tags: css, animation, svg, transform

I'm having a heck of a time getting my transform origin correct on a nested SVG element and was wondering if I could borrow someones eyes to maybe spot my folly?

I've tried a number of different combinations and so far when I tend to get close to what I want in one browser, it's quite off on another.

For the PoC example we're looking at my little dude's propeller. I set the transform origin for this example at just center for the sake of an easy start (like I said, I tried a number of variations with no luck yet). Could anyone please tell me what's causing the differences between browsers (yes I tried specifying transforms in the various browser qualifiers like -webkit-* as well and hitting the X/Y in various ways) but you'll notice in Chrome it's a lot closer to center of the element, whereas in Firefox it appears the origin the center of the absolute parent SVG itself...

So, anyone want to teach me something new about nested element transform origins in SVG animations and help my little dude fly with his propeller where it needs to be? :)

> [CODEPEN to tinker with](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/qXmyGJ)

PS - The vertical Green center line is just a visual size reference placeholder where my little dude flying it is in the real code since I can only add so many characters to an SO snippet...

```css
body {text-align:center}


@keyframes adventure {
  
  10% {
    transform: translateX(5%) rotate(2deg);
  } 25% {
    transform: translateX(13%) rotate(15deg);
  } 50% {
    transform: translateX(-13%) rotate(-5deg);
  } 75% {
    transform: translateX(13%) rotate(15deg);
  } 90% {
    transform: translateX(-5%) rotate(-2deg);
  }
  
}

@keyframes navigate {
  10% {
    transform: rotate(2deg);
  } 25% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  } 50% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  } 75% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  } 90% {
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
  }
}

@keyframes propel { 
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}

#fullcharacter {
  transform-origin: 50%;
  animation: adventure 5s infinite;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: step-start;
  transition-timing-function: step-start;
}


#steering {
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: navigate 5s infinite;
}

#propeller {
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: propel 4s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="525px" height="250px" viewBox="0 0 525 250" enable-background="new 0 0 525 250" xml:space="preserve">
<rect fill="#81BFE9" width="525" height="250"/>
<g id="fullcharacter">
 <g id="steering">
  <path fill="#BE1E2D" d="M242.271,125.417c0,0.552-0.479,1-1.069,1h-3.03c-0.589,0-1.068-0.448-1.068-1l0,0
   c0-0.552,0.479-1,1.068-1h3.03C241.792,124.417,242.271,124.865,242.271,125.417L242.271,125.417z"/>
  <path fill="#BE1E2D" d="M286.358,125.417c0,0.551-0.479,1-1.068,1h-3.029c-0.59,0-1.068-0.449-1.068-1l0,0
   c0-0.552,0.479-0.999,1.068-0.999h3.029C285.88,124.417,286.358,124.865,286.358,125.417L286.358,125.417z"/>
  <g>
   <path fill="#DDAC85" stroke="#BA9168" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M239.87,127.589c0,0,3.407-2.738,4.75-2.583
    c1.664,0.192,5.234,2.8,5,4.458c-0.225,1.591-5.795,2.781-5.795,2.781L239.87,127.589z"/>
   <path fill="#DDAC85" stroke="#BA9168" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M284.354,127.589
    c0,0-3.407-2.738-4.75-2.583c-1.664,0.192-5.234,2.8-5,4.458c0.225,1.591,5.795,2.781,5.795,2.781L284.354,127.589z"/>
  </g>
  <path fill="#D6A685" stroke="#BA9168" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M290.434,134.938
   c0,0,4.426,6.422,4.673,9.203c0.171,1.925-0.751,6.394-2.025,7.245c-1.815,1.214-7.728-3.23-7.728-3.23L290.434,134.938z"/>
  <path fill="#424142" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M287.158,126.417h-0.908v-0.833h-5v0.833
   h-0.993c0.003,0.117,0.015,0.229,0.015,0.348v15.422c0,4.61-2.687,8.349-6,8.349h-25c-3.313,0-6-3.738-6-8.349v-15.422
   c0-0.118,0.011-0.23,0.015-0.348h-1.119v-0.833h-5v0.833h-1.199c-0.124,0.669-0.197,1.365-0.197,2.087v22.147
   c0,4.61,2.687,8.349,6,8.349h39.583c3.313,0,6-3.738,6-8.349v-22.147C287.354,127.782,287.281,127.086,287.158,126.417z"/>
  <path fill="#D6A685" stroke="#BA9168" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M232.42,134.938
   c0,0-4.425,6.422-4.673,9.203c-0.171,1.925,0.751,6.394,2.025,7.245c1.815,1.214,7.727-3.23,7.727-3.23L232.42,134.938z"/>
  <g>
   <path fill="#EBB789" stroke="#C3996B" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M232.876,145.963
    c0,0,0.137,0.129-0.119,0.128c-0.902-0.003,0.79,2.842,1.599,3.242c2.943,1.456,11.196,0.29,12.908-2.524
    c0.376-0.617,0.248-3.348-0.285-2.873c-1.528,1.364-4.473,0.662-4.473,0.662s2.94,0.374,4.415-0.846
    c0.787-0.65,1.082-4.528,0.128-4.141c-2.34,0.95-5.744,0.766-5.744,0.766s3.64-0.21,5.679-0.978
    c1.147-0.433,1.245-5.443,0.125-4.928c-2.998,1.379-6.156,1.212-6.156,1.212s3.492,0.042,6.086-1.379
    c1.555-0.851,0.382-7.08-1.396-6.944c-7.403,0.563-11.077,0.177-12.742,1.556c-0.732,0.605-2.092,4.076-1.278,4.599
    c0.773,0.496,1.112,0.793,1.112,0.793s-0.139,0.041-1.157-0.6c-1.301-0.816-1.986,5.729-0.506,6.143
    c0.524,0.146,0.222,0.063,0.222,0.063s0.467,0.146-0.268,0.129c-1.533-0.036,0.135,5.875,1.669,5.911
    C232.958,145.96,232.876,145.963,232.876,145.963z"/>
   <path fill="#DDA885" d="M234.458,148.958c0,0,3.333,1.917,10.792-0.958c2.289-0.882,2.256-3.986,1.541-3.312
    c-0.75,0.708-2.539,0.791-3.416,0.479c-1.875-0.667,2.438,2.127,1.75,2.416C239.068,150.126,234.458,148.958,234.458,148.958z"/>
   <path fill="#DDA885" d="M241.688,140.75c0,0,2.303,0.095,3.063,0c0.632-0.079,2.472-0.625,2.472-0.625s-0.08,1.388-0.159,1.844
    c-0.063,0.358-0.375,1.406-0.375,1.406s-0.953-1.477-1.438-1.781C244.476,141.105,241.688,140.75,241.688,140.75z"/>
   <path fill="#DDA885" d="M241.094,136.094c0,0,2.758-0.124,3.656-0.313c0.639-0.134,2.472-0.844,2.472-0.844
    s0.249,1.736,0.185,2.313c-0.049,0.447-0.531,1.719-0.531,1.719s-0.391-1.796-0.844-2.156
    C245.054,136.037,241.094,136.094,241.094,136.094z"/>
   <path fill="#DDA885" d="M239.068,128.156c0,0,2.998-0.086,3.995-0.156c0.697-0.049,2.781-0.281,2.781-0.281
    s0.877,1.128,1.063,1.563c0.238,0.559,0.5,2.375,0.5,2.375s-1.416-2.35-2.188-2.781
    C243.868,128.119,239.068,128.156,239.068,128.156z"/>
   <path fill="#EBB789" stroke="#C3996B" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M291.052,145.963
    c0,0-0.138,0.129,0.119,0.128c0.901-0.003-0.79,2.842-1.599,3.242c-2.943,1.456-11.196,0.29-12.908-2.524
    c-0.376-0.617-0.248-3.348,0.285-2.873c1.527,1.364,4.473,0.662,4.473,0.662s-2.94,0.374-4.415-0.846
    c-0.786-0.65-1.082-4.528-0.128-4.141c2.34,0.95,5.743,0.766,5.743,0.766s-3.64-0.21-5.679-0.978
    c-1.148-0.433-1.246-5.443-0.126-4.928c2.997,1.379,6.155,1.212,6.155,1.212s-3.492,0.042-6.086-1.379
    c-1.555-0.851-0.381-7.08,1.396-6.944c7.403,0.563,11.077,0.177,12.742,1.556c0.732,0.605,2.092,4.076,1.279,4.599
    c-0.773,0.496-1.112,0.793-1.112,0.793s0.14,0.041,1.157-0.6c1.301-0.816,1.986,5.729,0.506,6.143
    c-0.523,0.146-0.222,0.063-0.222,0.063s-0.468,0.146,0.269,0.129c1.532-0.036-0.136,5.875-1.67,5.911
    C290.971,145.96,291.052,145.963,291.052,145.963z"/>
   <path fill="#DDA885" d="M289.469,148.958c0,0-3.332,1.917-10.791-0.958c-2.289-0.882-2.256-3.986-1.541-3.312
    c0.75,0.708,2.539,0.791,3.416,0.479c1.875-0.667-2.438,2.127-1.75,2.416C284.859,150.126,289.469,148.958,289.469,148.958z"/>
   <path fill="#DDA885" d="M282.24,140.75c0,0-2.303,0.095-3.063,0c-0.633-0.079-2.472-0.625-2.472-0.625s0.079,1.388,0.159,1.844
    c0.063,0.358,0.375,1.406,0.375,1.406s0.953-1.477,1.438-1.781C279.452,141.105,282.24,140.75,282.24,140.75z"/>
   <path fill="#DDA885" d="M282.834,136.094c0,0-2.758-0.124-3.656-0.313c-0.639-0.134-2.472-0.844-2.472-0.844
    s-0.249,1.736-0.185,2.313c0.049,0.447,0.531,1.719,0.531,1.719s0.391-1.796,0.844-2.156
    C278.873,136.037,282.834,136.094,282.834,136.094z"/>
   <path fill="#DDA885" d="M284.859,128.156c0,0-2.997-0.086-3.994-0.156c-0.697-0.049-2.781-0.281-2.781-0.281
    s-0.877,1.128-1.063,1.563c-0.238,0.559-0.5,2.375-0.5,2.375s1.416-2.35,2.188-2.781
    C280.06,128.119,284.859,128.156,284.859,128.156z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="plane">
  <path fill="#CE3232" stroke="#931C24" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M297.126,174.5c0,0,55.101,6.274,72.374,12.5
   c0.949,0.342,3.408,1.002,3.5,2.006c0.192,2.118-4.514,4.733-6.5,5.494c-15.415,5.906-66.001,2-66.001,2L297.126,174.5z"/>
  <path fill="#CE3232" stroke="#931C24" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M225.507,174.5c0,0-55.101,6.274-72.374,12.5
   c-0.949,0.342-3.408,1.002-3.5,2.006c-0.192,2.118,4.514,4.733,6.5,5.494c15.415,5.906,66.001,2,66.001,2L225.507,174.5z"/>
  
   <ellipse fill="#CE3232" stroke="#931C24" stroke-width="0.75" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="260.962" cy="189.006" rx="49.754" ry="42.661"/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="246.625" y1="149.8066" x2="276.7061" y2="149.8066">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#5BCBF1"/>
   <stop  offset="0.0017" style="stop-color:#5BCAF1"/>
   <stop  offset="0.1744" style="stop-color:#4197D1"/>
   <stop  offset="0.3181" style="stop-color:#2F78BC"/>
   <stop  offset="0.4256" style="stop-color:#2467B1"/>
   <stop  offset="0.4848" style="stop-color:#2061AE"/>
   <stop  offset="0.6679" style="stop-color:#2C66B1"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#3B6EB6"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <path fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" stroke="#004C6D" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M246.625,151.596
   c0,0,2.098,2.086,3.006,2.404c5.572,1.955,17.985,1.766,23.619,0c1.004-0.314,3.456-2.404,3.456-2.404s-3.442-6.027-5.433-7.002
   c-2.223-1.089-7.133,0.531-9.608,0.531c-2.313,0-7.461-1.542-9.541-0.531C250.123,145.567,246.625,151.596,246.625,151.596z"/>
  <path fill="#BF312F" d="M261.375,219.229c-25.047,0-45.655-16.281-48.226-37.173c-0.444,2.261-0.688,4.581-0.688,6.95
   c0,22.967,21.714,41.585,48.5,41.585c26.787,0,48.5-18.618,48.5-41.585c0-1.491-0.096-2.963-0.274-4.413
   C305.328,204.249,285.398,219.229,261.375,219.229z"/>
  <ellipse fill="#969696" stroke="#BCBEC0" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="260.962" cy="189.006" rx="27.5" ry="25"/>
  <radialGradient id="propeller_1_" cx="261.3926" cy="188.5" r="50.9983" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <stop  offset="0.3011" style="stop-color:#BCBEC0"/>
   <stop  offset="0.4531" style="stop-color:#E6E7E8"/>
   <stop  offset="0.9899" style="stop-color:#F1F2F2"/>
   <stop  offset="0.9936" style="stop-color:#F9ED32"/>
  </radialGradient>
  <path id="propeller" fill="url(#propeller_1_)" stroke="#6D6E71" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M291.618,198.024
   l-25.939-12.274l2.33-28.48c0,0-0.02-31.189-6.862-31.182c-6.844,0.009-7.013,31.18-7.013,31.18l2.598,28.423l-26.065,12.334
   c0,0-27.001,15.611-23.572,21.534c3.429,5.923,30.507-9.517,30.507-9.517l23.541-16.62l23.541,16.62
   c0,0,27.079,15.439,30.507,9.517C318.62,213.636,291.618,198.024,291.618,198.024z M261.155,188.442l-0.013,0.022l-0.013-0.022
   H261.155z"/>
  <radialGradient id="SVGID_2_" cx="261.1426" cy="189.0049" r="11.9452" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#D1D3D4"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#A7A9AC"/>
  </radialGradient>
  
   <ellipse fill="url(#SVGID_2_)" stroke="#6D6E71" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="261.143" cy="189.005" rx="12.5" ry="11.363"/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="155.7402" y1="175.625" x2="177.2904" y2="150.7379">
   <stop  offset="0.01" style="stop-color:#BCBEC0"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <polygon fill="url(#SVGID_3_)" points="149.627,187.171 180.5,140.842 152,186.134   "/>
  
   <linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="59.2358" y1="175.626" x2="80.786" y2="150.7389" gradientTransform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 426.1279 0)">
   <stop  offset="0.01" style="stop-color:#BCBEC0"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <polygon fill="url(#SVGID_4_)" points="373.006,187.171 342.133,140.842 370.633,186.134   "/>
 </g>
 <rect x="260.5" y="13.75" fill="#6CBE45" width="0.462" height="217.917"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Firefox is right, Chrome is wrong. Chrome intend to fix their implementation at some point.

Comment: @RobertLongson Just the man I was hoping to chime in! I figured one had to be an implementation issue but got any tips for hitting the transform origin correctly for the propeller itself and at least get it correct for one of them for now? I'm getting to a point where I was about to approach it programmatically and see what I could do with JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really use percentage values for `transform-origin` right now because percentage values are treated differently in Chrome and Firefox.  That applies also to pseudo values like "center" which is defined to be equivalent to "50%".

You need to use absolute pixel values instead to be cross-browser compatible.

If you change your propellor animation, to use absolute coordinates, it will fix the animation:

```
#propeller {
  transform-origin: 261px 189px;
  animation: propel 4s infinite linear;
}
```

The coordinates I used here were just the `cx` and `cy` values of the `<ellipse>` that forms the propellor hub.

```css
body {text-align:center}


@keyframes adventure {
  
  10% {
    transform: translateX(5%) rotate(2deg);
  } 25% {
    transform: translateX(13%) rotate(15deg);
  } 50% {
    transform: translateX(-13%) rotate(-5deg);
  } 75% {
    transform: translateX(13%) rotate(15deg);
  } 90% {
    transform: translateX(-5%) rotate(-2deg);
  }
  
}

@keyframes navigate {
  10% {
    transform: rotate(2deg);
  } 25% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  } 50% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  } 75% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  } 90% {
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
  }
}

@keyframes propel { 
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}

#fullcharacter {
  transform-origin: 50%;
  animation: adventure 5s infinite;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: step-start;
  transition-timing-function: step-start;
}


#steering {
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: navigate 5s infinite;
}

#propeller {
  transform-origin: 261px 189px;
  animation: propel 4s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="525px" height="250px" viewBox="0 0 525 250" enable-background="new 0 0 525 250" xml:space="preserve">
<rect fill="#81BFE9" width="525" height="250"/>
<g id="fullcharacter">
 <g id="steering">
  <path fill="#BE1E2D" d="M242.271,125.417c0,0.552-0.479,1-1.069,1h-3.03c-0.589,0-1.068-0.448-1.068-1l0,0
   c0-0.552,0.479-1,1.068-1h3.03C241.792,124.417,242.271,124.865,242.271,125.417L242.271,125.417z"/>
  <path fill="#BE1E2D" d="M286.358,125.417c0,0.551-0.479,1-1.068,1h-3.029c-0.59,0-1.068-0.449-1.068-1l0,0
   c0-0.552,0.479-0.999,1.068-0.999h3.029C285.88,124.417,286.358,124.865,286.358,125.417L286.358,125.417z"/>
  <g>
   <path fill="#DDAC85" stroke="#BA9168" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M239.87,127.589c0,0,3.407-2.738,4.75-2.583
    c1.664,0.192,5.234,2.8,5,4.458c-0.225,1.591-5.795,2.781-5.795,2.781L239.87,127.589z"/>
   <path fill="#DDAC85" stroke="#BA9168" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M284.354,127.589
    c0,0-3.407-2.738-4.75-2.583c-1.664,0.192-5.234,2.8-5,4.458c0.225,1.591,5.795,2.781,5.795,2.781L284.354,127.589z"/>
  </g>
  <path fill="#D6A685" stroke="#BA9168" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M290.434,134.938
   c0,0,4.426,6.422,4.673,9.203c0.171,1.925-0.751,6.394-2.025,7.245c-1.815,1.214-7.728-3.23-7.728-3.23L290.434,134.938z"/>
  <path fill="#424142" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M287.158,126.417h-0.908v-0.833h-5v0.833
   h-0.993c0.003,0.117,0.015,0.229,0.015,0.348v15.422c0,4.61-2.687,8.349-6,8.349h-25c-3.313,0-6-3.738-6-8.349v-15.422
   c0-0.118,0.011-0.23,0.015-0.348h-1.119v-0.833h-5v0.833h-1.199c-0.124,0.669-0.197,1.365-0.197,2.087v22.147
   c0,4.61,2.687,8.349,6,8.349h39.583c3.313,0,6-3.738,6-8.349v-22.147C287.354,127.782,287.281,127.086,287.158,126.417z"/>
  <path fill="#D6A685" stroke="#BA9168" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M232.42,134.938
   c0,0-4.425,6.422-4.673,9.203c-0.171,1.925,0.751,6.394,2.025,7.245c1.815,1.214,7.727-3.23,7.727-3.23L232.42,134.938z"/>
  <g>
   <path fill="#EBB789" stroke="#C3996B" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M232.876,145.963
    c0,0,0.137,0.129-0.119,0.128c-0.902-0.003,0.79,2.842,1.599,3.242c2.943,1.456,11.196,0.29,12.908-2.524
    c0.376-0.617,0.248-3.348-0.285-2.873c-1.528,1.364-4.473,0.662-4.473,0.662s2.94,0.374,4.415-0.846
    c0.787-0.65,1.082-4.528,0.128-4.141c-2.34,0.95-5.744,0.766-5.744,0.766s3.64-0.21,5.679-0.978
    c1.147-0.433,1.245-5.443,0.125-4.928c-2.998,1.379-6.156,1.212-6.156,1.212s3.492,0.042,6.086-1.379
    c1.555-0.851,0.382-7.08-1.396-6.944c-7.403,0.563-11.077,0.177-12.742,1.556c-0.732,0.605-2.092,4.076-1.278,4.599
    c0.773,0.496,1.112,0.793,1.112,0.793s-0.139,0.041-1.157-0.6c-1.301-0.816-1.986,5.729-0.506,6.143
    c0.524,0.146,0.222,0.063,0.222,0.063s0.467,0.146-0.268,0.129c-1.533-0.036,0.135,5.875,1.669,5.911
    C232.958,145.96,232.876,145.963,232.876,145.963z"/>
   <path fill="#DDA885" d="M234.458,148.958c0,0,3.333,1.917,10.792-0.958c2.289-0.882,2.256-3.986,1.541-3.312
    c-0.75,0.708-2.539,0.791-3.416,0.479c-1.875-0.667,2.438,2.127,1.75,2.416C239.068,150.126,234.458,148.958,234.458,148.958z"/>
   <path fill="#DDA885" d="M241.688,140.75c0,0,2.303,0.095,3.063,0c0.632-0.079,2.472-0.625,2.472-0.625s-0.08,1.388-0.159,1.844
    c-0.063,0.358-0.375,1.406-0.375,1.406s-0.953-1.477-1.438-1.781C244.476,141.105,241.688,140.75,241.688,140.75z"/>
   <path fill="#DDA885" d="M241.094,136.094c0,0,2.758-0.124,3.656-0.313c0.639-0.134,2.472-0.844,2.472-0.844
    s0.249,1.736,0.185,2.313c-0.049,0.447-0.531,1.719-0.531,1.719s-0.391-1.796-0.844-2.156
    C245.054,136.037,241.094,136.094,241.094,136.094z"/>
   <path fill="#DDA885" d="M239.068,128.156c0,0,2.998-0.086,3.995-0.156c0.697-0.049,2.781-0.281,2.781-0.281
    s0.877,1.128,1.063,1.563c0.238,0.559,0.5,2.375,0.5,2.375s-1.416-2.35-2.188-2.781
    C243.868,128.119,239.068,128.156,239.068,128.156z"/>
   <path fill="#EBB789" stroke="#C3996B" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M291.052,145.963
    c0,0-0.138,0.129,0.119,0.128c0.901-0.003-0.79,2.842-1.599,3.242c-2.943,1.456-11.196,0.29-12.908-2.524
    c-0.376-0.617-0.248-3.348,0.285-2.873c1.527,1.364,4.473,0.662,4.473,0.662s-2.94,0.374-4.415-0.846
    c-0.786-0.65-1.082-4.528-0.128-4.141c2.34,0.95,5.743,0.766,5.743,0.766s-3.64-0.21-5.679-0.978
    c-1.148-0.433-1.246-5.443-0.126-4.928c2.997,1.379,6.155,1.212,6.155,1.212s-3.492,0.042-6.086-1.379
    c-1.555-0.851-0.381-7.08,1.396-6.944c7.403,0.563,11.077,0.177,12.742,1.556c0.732,0.605,2.092,4.076,1.279,4.599
    c-0.773,0.496-1.112,0.793-1.112,0.793s0.14,0.041,1.157-0.6c1.301-0.816,1.986,5.729,0.506,6.143
    c-0.523,0.146-0.222,0.063-0.222,0.063s-0.468,0.146,0.269,0.129c1.532-0.036-0.136,5.875-1.67,5.911
    C290.971,145.96,291.052,145.963,291.052,145.963z"/>
   <path fill="#DDA885" d="M289.469,148.958c0,0-3.332,1.917-10.791-0.958c-2.289-0.882-2.256-3.986-1.541-3.312
    c0.75,0.708,2.539,0.791,3.416,0.479c1.875-0.667-2.438,2.127-1.75,2.416C284.859,150.126,289.469,148.958,289.469,148.958z"/>
   <path fill="#DDA885" d="M282.24,140.75c0,0-2.303,0.095-3.063,0c-0.633-0.079-2.472-0.625-2.472-0.625s0.079,1.388,0.159,1.844
    c0.063,0.358,0.375,1.406,0.375,1.406s0.953-1.477,1.438-1.781C279.452,141.105,282.24,140.75,282.24,140.75z"/>
   <path fill="#DDA885" d="M282.834,136.094c0,0-2.758-0.124-3.656-0.313c-0.639-0.134-2.472-0.844-2.472-0.844
    s-0.249,1.736-0.185,2.313c0.049,0.447,0.531,1.719,0.531,1.719s0.391-1.796,0.844-2.156
    C278.873,136.037,282.834,136.094,282.834,136.094z"/>
   <path fill="#DDA885" d="M284.859,128.156c0,0-2.997-0.086-3.994-0.156c-0.697-0.049-2.781-0.281-2.781-0.281
    s-0.877,1.128-1.063,1.563c-0.238,0.559-0.5,2.375-0.5,2.375s1.416-2.35,2.188-2.781
    C280.06,128.119,284.859,128.156,284.859,128.156z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="plane">
  <path fill="#CE3232" stroke="#931C24" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M297.126,174.5c0,0,55.101,6.274,72.374,12.5
   c0.949,0.342,3.408,1.002,3.5,2.006c0.192,2.118-4.514,4.733-6.5,5.494c-15.415,5.906-66.001,2-66.001,2L297.126,174.5z"/>
  <path fill="#CE3232" stroke="#931C24" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M225.507,174.5c0,0-55.101,6.274-72.374,12.5
   c-0.949,0.342-3.408,1.002-3.5,2.006c-0.192,2.118,4.514,4.733,6.5,5.494c15.415,5.906,66.001,2,66.001,2L225.507,174.5z"/>
  
   <ellipse fill="#CE3232" stroke="#931C24" stroke-width="0.75" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="260.962" cy="189.006" rx="49.754" ry="42.661"/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="246.625" y1="149.8066" x2="276.7061" y2="149.8066">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#5BCBF1"/>
   <stop  offset="0.0017" style="stop-color:#5BCAF1"/>
   <stop  offset="0.1744" style="stop-color:#4197D1"/>
   <stop  offset="0.3181" style="stop-color:#2F78BC"/>
   <stop  offset="0.4256" style="stop-color:#2467B1"/>
   <stop  offset="0.4848" style="stop-color:#2061AE"/>
   <stop  offset="0.6679" style="stop-color:#2C66B1"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#3B6EB6"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <path fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" stroke="#004C6D" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M246.625,151.596
   c0,0,2.098,2.086,3.006,2.404c5.572,1.955,17.985,1.766,23.619,0c1.004-0.314,3.456-2.404,3.456-2.404s-3.442-6.027-5.433-7.002
   c-2.223-1.089-7.133,0.531-9.608,0.531c-2.313,0-7.461-1.542-9.541-0.531C250.123,145.567,246.625,151.596,246.625,151.596z"/>
  <path fill="#BF312F" d="M261.375,219.229c-25.047,0-45.655-16.281-48.226-37.173c-0.444,2.261-0.688,4.581-0.688,6.95
   c0,22.967,21.714,41.585,48.5,41.585c26.787,0,48.5-18.618,48.5-41.585c0-1.491-0.096-2.963-0.274-4.413
   C305.328,204.249,285.398,219.229,261.375,219.229z"/>
  <ellipse fill="#969696" stroke="#BCBEC0" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="260.962" cy="189.006" rx="27.5" ry="25"/>
  <radialGradient id="propeller_1_" cx="261.3926" cy="188.5" r="50.9983" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <stop  offset="0.3011" style="stop-color:#BCBEC0"/>
   <stop  offset="0.4531" style="stop-color:#E6E7E8"/>
   <stop  offset="0.9899" style="stop-color:#F1F2F2"/>
   <stop  offset="0.9936" style="stop-color:#F9ED32"/>
  </radialGradient>
  <path id="propeller" fill="url(#propeller_1_)" stroke="#6D6E71" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M291.618,198.024
   l-25.939-12.274l2.33-28.48c0,0-0.02-31.189-6.862-31.182c-6.844,0.009-7.013,31.18-7.013,31.18l2.598,28.423l-26.065,12.334
   c0,0-27.001,15.611-23.572,21.534c3.429,5.923,30.507-9.517,30.507-9.517l23.541-16.62l23.541,16.62
   c0,0,27.079,15.439,30.507,9.517C318.62,213.636,291.618,198.024,291.618,198.024z M261.155,188.442l-0.013,0.022l-0.013-0.022
   H261.155z"/>
  <radialGradient id="SVGID_2_" cx="261.1426" cy="189.0049" r="11.9452" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#D1D3D4"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#A7A9AC"/>
  </radialGradient>
  
   <ellipse fill="url(#SVGID_2_)" stroke="#6D6E71" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="261.143" cy="189.005" rx="12.5" ry="11.363"/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="155.7402" y1="175.625" x2="177.2904" y2="150.7379">
   <stop  offset="0.01" style="stop-color:#BCBEC0"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <polygon fill="url(#SVGID_3_)" points="149.627,187.171 180.5,140.842 152,186.134   "/>
  
   <linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="59.2358" y1="175.626" x2="80.786" y2="150.7389" gradientTransform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 426.1279 0)">
   <stop  offset="0.01" style="stop-color:#BCBEC0"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <polygon fill="url(#SVGID_4_)" points="373.006,187.171 342.133,140.842 370.633,186.134   "/>
 </g>
 <rect x="260.5" y="13.75" fill="#6CBE45" width="0.462" height="217.917"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: That sir is a winner thank you! I needed it origin for what I had in mind to do with it forward. I could have SWORN I had already tried that --- Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using transform origin, set the center of the rotation with 2 diferent translates.

(you move the element to wherever you want, rotate it, and move it back to where it was).

Your animation will be

```
@keyframes propel { 
    0% {transform: translate(257px, 188px) rotate(0deg) translate(-257px, -188px);}
  100% {transform: translate(257px, 188px) rotate(360deg) translate(-257px, -188px);}
}
```

[fixed codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rzmQxM)